# how to import uv maps into unity?

Tags: unity, blender, uv-mapping

Im trying to create a model using blender and import it to unity. I can import the model and get the texture working but the texture uv map is not correct. I have a uv layout map file I exported but not sure if there is some way to apply it in unity. Any help would be appreciated.

blender:
[image]

unity:
[image]

Comment: The UV map is part of the mesh file, not.something you import separately. Do you perhaps have some type of scaling or tiling modifier active in Blender that has not been baked down into the mesh UVs?

Comment: I don't think so. I create a new file to test and its just a unit cube with all transforms rest. I then use blendkit to apply a brick texture. I then do a uv unwrap. Then I pack+unpack the file to extract textures. Lastly in unity I import the material and apply the textures to the material. In new to unity and somewhat new to blender so I'm probably missing something stupid. Could it be some addon screwing something up?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but .obj seems to work while .fbx does not, no matter what I try. I guess the main difference between file types is .fbx supports animations. I have no plan to work on animations any time real soon so I'm not going to use .fbx format.

Blender:

[image]

Unity:

[image]

There are so many posts about this issue in Unity forums going back several years. Many people are not happy about it.

It's not all roses though. For posterity these are my .fbx export settings:

Setting path to **copy** seems important based on forums but it doesn't seem to do anything. It supposedly copies the texture into the obj. However after importing to Unity I had to still do several things:

- I pack then unpack the file in Blender which creates a textures folder.
- Then I copy the textures to unity. I have to select my obj and click export materials.
- Then manually copy the textures directly to the materials. Its rubbish and no idea if it will work for all models. Too much information to explain every step without a video.

[image]

Comment: I notice you've left "triangulated mesh" unchecked. Do you observe any difference if you check that box?